# Hidden input fiel in IE9 only fires after double click

Tags: file-upload, input, internet-explorer-9

i have a hidden `input type:file` field laying over my button for opening the window for an file upload, it works in all browsers except the IE9. In the IE9 the window only opens after a double click on the field.

Comment: same probleme here! ie 10 has the same problem.